# Unit testing with jdeveloper 10g

Tags: junit, tdd, jdeveloper

I want to use JUnit or similiar TDD frameworks and plugins at my work environment. But where I work, migrating to jdeveloper 11g or eclipse is not considerable in a near future. 
We are using jdeveloper 10g for development and I can't find any resources about tutoring TDD on Jdeveloper 10g. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

From JDeveloper, Help->Check for updates->Install the Junit extensions

Then check out this link to get you started...

http://blogs.oracle.com/bwb/entry/unit_testing_with_junit_and